# Here does not render polyline properly since HERE android sdk V3.9 upgrade

Tags: android, here-api

We are using HERE android premium sdk to build our custom navigation application, and since the last upgrade (we've upgraded from 3.7 to 3.9), we have noticed a bug in the rendering of polylines.

Some polylines are not shown when at certain "tilt" or "orientation". My guess is that the algorithm that detects wether an object is or is not to be displayed is flawed. I've recorded a video of the issue : https://youtu.be/pofaCFyUBcs

A similar video, with the exact same code, but with here android sdk v3.7 : https://youtu.be/Uxc7eKvyMVs

Can you provide support on how to avoid this issue ? Will it be fixed in next version ?

Comment: Could provide more info: device, geo coordinates etc? Did you create route via custom polyline objects or using CoureRouter?

Comment: I asked here support by mail and they acknwloedged this was a bug. They are working on it and expect it to be fixed in next release 3.11. They say it works with polylines with lesser than 150 coords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary:  Fixed in the SDK release 3.11. Additionally, it works with polylines with lesser than 150 coordinates.